# verb/lstinline text flows out of the line margins without line break in Latex

Tags: latex, formatting, margin, listings

The `listings` package supports line breaks inside `lstlisting` environment. But it doesn't produce automatic line breaks for `lstinline` environment. For example, in the following paragraph the first line flows out of the margins:

```
The parameters \lstinline|base_rmr_brain|, \lstinline|base_rmr_fat|, and \lstinline|baseline_basal_rmr_of_lean_tissues| are metabolic rates of brain, fat, and lean tissues in kcal/(kg*day). The parameter \lstinline|mass_brain| denotes the mass of the brain in gram.
```

Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The *literate* feature of listings could be helpful, e.g. to introduce linebreaks at underscores:

```
\lstset{
  literate={\_}{}{0\discretionary{\_}{}{\_}}%
}
```

Comment: Can the same idea be used for discretionary advice to use a linebreak for any such character; and not only underscores?

Comment: @user2023370 great question, and one that deserves an answer...